# Ferrite bead DC-resistance tolerance

Tags: ferrite-bead, tolerance

What is the DC-resistance tolerance for a smd ferrite bead (e.g. BLM18RK102SN1D)?
Does anyone know? The datasheets I have seen only give a maximum value for the DC-resistance.

Comment: Why isn't the maximum value good enough? Lower is always better in this case. Do you need an specific value or something? If you do, I think you may be  misusing the ferrite bead.

Comment: I am using it in a DC voltage rail. So I dont think I am misusing it. The point is, that the beads' DC resistance, when changing throughout multiple devices, affects a DC measurement on that rail. I just want to know the lowest DC-resistance in order to calculate the min. max. values for that DC measurement.

Comment: @stowoda In that case, the minimum is zero. This is the minimum to use in your worst case production yield calculations. It's a very bad and flaky design that relies on a non-zero minimum resistance in its power supply distribution conductors. You could measure many devices, and use a 3sigma or 6sigma distance for the distribution, but what happens when a different batch turns up? Surely the difference between zero and typical for a ferrite bead resistance is way less than the other tolerances in your DC power supply?

Comment: @Neil_UK zero is tough, though thats theoretically the way to go :/. R_dc_min we simply dont know and must assume some number approaching 0. Maybe the manufacturer can tell something about that parameter..